# Put a tooltip on css shape

Tags: css, hover, tooltip, geometry, shapes

I have circle shapes that are made of CSS, i'm trying to put a tool-tip that appears when i hover into the circle, any ideas on how to do that?
Here is my circle code:

```css
#circle1 {
 width: 52px;
 height: 52px;
 background: #f5e25d;
    opacity: 0.9
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting an HTML element inside `#circle1` (I used a `span`) for the tooltip, and using `#circle1:hover` to display the tooltip. Then I put a triangle as the `::after` pseudo-element for the `span`. I used a [CSS Triangle Generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) to create the tooltip triangle.

```css
.wrap {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#circle1 {
  display: block;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  background: #f5e25d;
  opacity: 0.9 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto auto;
  position: relative;
}

span.tooltip {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(100% + 20px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 200px;
  background: #444;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span.tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #444444 transparent transparent transparent;
}

#circle1:hover span.tooltip {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a id="circle1">
    <span class="tooltip">Tooltip, baby, yeah!</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, a tooltip is something that looks like this https://webdesignerhut.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/pure-css-tooltips.png 
you gave me half of the answer with the triangle

Comment: @stephjhonny Updated.

Comment: Awesome, happy to help!